# FileMaker Server 11 & Windows Server 2008 R2 VMware & CWP

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, filemaker

Ok, so here is the background:

---

Our company has finally decided to migrate the current FileMaker Server Advanced 10 installations from physical machines running windows server 2003. As a test, we migrated our development machine to a new VMWare Windows server 2008 R2 enterprise installation. We can connect through FM clients with no problem. We deployed Custom Web Publishing, Instant Web Publishing, XSLT and ODBC. The FileMaker server Test page succeeds in testing CWP, IWP and XSLT with no problem. However, when I attempt to access ANY of the 57 files, including the FMServer_Sample file, I get errors.

using the following php, I get an error returned of (959), which according to FileMaker is that the CWP service is not running. An entry IS being created in the FileMaker Server log, so I know it's hitting the server. If I point it at any of the 4 other servers, I get correct results. But I am baffled on this one.

```
<?php

require_once('FileMaker.php');
require_once('Config.php');


$fm = new FileMaker('FMServer_Sample', '127.0.0.1', 'Admin', '12345');
$request = $fm->newFindAllCommand('English_Form_View');
$result = $request->execute();
if (FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    echo 'FileMaker server error: ' . $result->message . '(' . $result->code . ')';
} else {
    $records = $result->getRecords();
    foreach ($records as $r) {
        echo $r->getField('Title');
    }
}
```